# How should I print formated text from a txt file with python?

Tags: python, regex

I got this file with this info pattern:

```
# Query 1: 204.60k QPS, 230.79x concurrency, ID XXXXXXXXXX at byte 19XXX9318
# This item is included in the report because it matches --limit.
# Scores: V/M = 0.00
# Time range: 2020-01-29 18:18:59.073995 to 18:18:59.074005
# Attribute    pct   total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# ============ === ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======
# Count          7       2
# Exec time     10     2ms     1ms     1ms     1ms     1ms    12us     1ms
# Rows affecte   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Query size     7      74      37      37      37      37       0      37
# Warning coun   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# String:
# Hosts        10.1.1.5 (1/50%), 10.8.0.2 (1/50%)
# Query_time distribution
#   1us
#  10us
# 100us
#   1ms  ################################################################
#  10ms
# 100ms
#    1s
#  10s+
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'XXXXX'\G
\n break line 
repeat
```

I want to run a script in python to get only some information from that file. There will be multiple querys.

Currently Im trying something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

file = open("/etc/openvpn/logs/log-2020_01_29_06_20_PM.txt", "r")
read = file.read()
removeChar = read.replace("#", "")
for item in removeChar.split("\n"):
        if "Hosts" and "Time range" in item:
                print item.strip()
```

The output is:

```
Time range: 2020-01-29 18:18:59.073995 to 18:18:59.074005
Time range: 2020-01-29 18:18:58.489162 to 18:18:59.188582
Time range: 2020-01-29 18:18:58.666020 to 18:18:58.666028
```

I want it to be something like this:

```
['Query 1, 2020-01-29 18:18:59, 10.1.1.5, 10.8.0.2, SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'XXXXX'\G']
['Query 2, 2020-01-29 18:19:59, 10.1.1.5, 10.8.0.2, SHOW FROM BLA * LIKE 'BLA'\G']
```

Im tired of trying to find how to do this, also I'm learning python because it is a good language to learn! :)

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should try numpy to read file. I see the file is with fixed length and you remove all spaces, you can try using a semicolon and then, with numpy treat it like a csv file.

Comment: The way is. I run tcpdump command to extract network packages, then I use pt-query-digest to get all the queries done and It always print like that, just changing the values inside. I don't know the anwsers about that questions..

Comment: Ok. First I think you should remove all lines that are not header of table neither table content. Then, numpy can handle that as a table, with headers and everything you might need.


`# Attribute    pct   total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# ============ === ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======
# Count          7       2
# Exec time     10     2ms     1ms     1ms     1ms     1ms    12us     1ms
# Query size     7      74      37      37      37      37       0      37`

Comment: I want to say a very complicated regex might be able to handle it, though it probably isn't the best solution. In the five minutes I had to work on it I came up with `r'(Query \d+).*?\b^Time Range: ([0-9-]+ [0-9:.]+).*?^Hosts(?:\s*([0-9.]+)[^,]*?)$.*?^(SHOW .*?)$'`, which didn't work but which you might be able to tweak so that it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try without regex, using string manipulation only:

```
data = '''# Query 1: 204.60k QPS, 230.79x concurrency, ID XXXXXXXXXX at byte 19XXX9318
# This item is included in the report because it matches --limit.
# Scores: V/M = 0.00
# Time range: 2020-01-29 18:18:59.073995 to 18:18:59.074005
# Attribute    pct   total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# ============ === ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======
# Count          7       2
# Exec time     10     2ms     1ms     1ms     1ms     1ms    12us     1ms
# Rows affecte   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Query size     7      74      37      37      37      37       0      37
# Warning coun   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# String:
# Hosts        10.1.1.5 (1/50%), 10.8.0.2 (1/50%)
# Query_time distribution
#   1us
#  10us
# 100us
#   1ms  ################################################################
#  10ms
# 100ms
#    1s
#  10s+
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'XXXXX'\G
\n break line 
repeat
'''

data = data.split('\n')

all_results = []

result = []

for row in data:
    if row.startswith('# Query ') and not row.startswith('# Query size'):
        row = row.split(':')[0].split('# ')[1]
        result.append(row)

    elif row.startswith('# Hosts'):
        row = row.replace('# Hosts', '').replace(' ', '').split(',')
        result.append(row[0].split('(')[0])
        result.append(row[1].split('(')[0])

    elif row.startswith('# Time range:'):
        row = row.replace('# Time range:', '').split('.')[0].strip()
        result.append(row)

    elif row.startswith('SHOW') and row.endswith('\G'):
        result.append(row)
        result = ', '.join(result)
        all_results.append(result)
        result = []

print(all_results)

    # output: "Query 1, 2020-01-29 18:18:59, 10.1.1.5, 10.8.0.2, SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'XXXXX'\\G"
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for that buddy! When I try to get a file and read it and use it says: IndexError: list index out of range. How can I overcome this? I want this to open a file and read it

Comment: At which line the error occurs? Or post if you can one of these files to test it.

Comment: I add a << [data = open("/path/to/file.txt", "r")] >> then I changed data split to << [data = data.read().split('\n')] >> and the error its on line 10 << [ result = [data[0].split(':')[0].split('# ')[1]]
IndexError: list index out of range]] >>

Comment: Does each file contains more than one query?

Comment: Yes. Its a file with weekly querys... and I want to format that all like that you did because the next step its to archive it all on database to see who did what :)

Comment: I've modified the code in answer to process multiple queries per file, please try it and tell me if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206981/discussion-between-henrique-mota-and-giannis-clipper).

Comment: Unfortunately I have to leave now, write me a new comment when you have any results from testing the code, if the problem exist it would be helpful to post a file with a number of queries inside, I will check the post later or tomorrow.

Comment: I leave a comment on chat, just open it when you can, thanks!!

Comment: I don't know how that chat work but I sent you a message buddy haha :) and thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regex and hardcode, here is an example:

```
import re

file_path = 'file.txt'

query_pattern = r'Query \d+'
date_time_pattern = r'\d\d\d\d-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) ' \
                    r'(00|[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])'
hosts_pattern = r'\d+\.\d+\.\d\.\d+'
final_pattern = r"SHOW.+\\G"

result = ''

with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    try:
        text = f.read()
        result += '{}, '.format(str(re.search(query_pattern, text)[0]))
        result += '{}, '.format(str(re.search(date_time_pattern, text)[0]))
        hosts = re.findall(hosts_pattern, text)
        result += '{}, {}, '.format(hosts[0], hosts[1])
        result += re.search(final_pattern, text)[0]
        print('Done!')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: \n{}'.format(e))


print(result)
```

Output:

```
Query 1, 2020-01-29 18:18:59, 10.1.1.5, 10.8.0.2, SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'XXXXX'\G
```

Comment: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute '__getitem__'